# Difference between $product->getResource()->save($product); $product->save();

Tags: magento-1.9, product

Can anyone know what is the difference between use of

> $product->getResource()->save($product);
>
> $product->save();

Answer (score 3):

There is not a huge difference. When calling save directly from the product object, that function also calls `$product->getResource()->save($product)`.

However, both the product model and product resource model can have `beforeSave()` and `afterSave()` events. So when you call  `$product->getResource()->save($product)`, you end up skipping the beforeSave/afterSave events that exist within the main product model and only those that exist within the resource model are called.

The main difference between the two, is that when calling `$product->save()`, it calls `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::_beforeSave()` which contains this logic:

```
/**
 * Check product options and type options and save them, too
 */
protected function _beforeSave()
{
    $this->cleanCache();
    $this->setTypeHasOptions(false);
    $this->setTypeHasRequiredOptions(false);

    $this->getTypeInstance(true)->beforeSave($this);

    $hasOptions         = false;
    $hasRequiredOptions = false;

    /**
     * $this->_canAffectOptions - set by type instance only
     * $this->getCanSaveCustomOptions() - set either in controller when "Custom Options" ajax tab is loaded,
     * or in type instance as well
     */
    $this->canAffectOptions($this->_canAffectOptions && $this->getCanSaveCustomOptions());
    if ($this->getCanSaveCustomOptions()) {
        $options = $this->getProductOptions();
        if (is_array($options)) {
            $this->setIsCustomOptionChanged(true);
            foreach ($this->getProductOptions() as $option) {
                $this->getOptionInstance()->addOption($option);
                if ((!isset($option['is_delete'])) || $option['is_delete'] != '1') {
                    $hasOptions = true;
                }
            }
            foreach ($this->getOptionInstance()->getOptions() as $option) {
                if ($option['is_require'] == '1') {
                    $hasRequiredOptions = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

After this runs, the same `$this->getResource()->save($this)` is called.

Comment: in my custom extention when i use $product->save(); it give me error and when i use other its works fine.

Comment: what's the error? and in your custom extension, is your product of the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` or is it using your custom class?

Comment: i create product programatically with use of my custom extension. when i change its qty and save product it gives error. so what is the main diffrent between those two method?

Comment: You need to tell me the exact error you are getting. Otherwise, it could be a million different things.

Comment: can you give me exact diffrent between those two?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you what really the only difference is but if I don't know what error you are getting and if you are not quite sure how to read the code, it would be really tough to help you.